# How to get remote client IP address from http request in ballerina

Tags: ballerina

The actual client who invoke the service  is in the    internal property "REMOTE_ADDRESS". But we can not retrieve it from ballerina http:Request .
Is there a way we can get the remote IP of the client from http request in ballerina

ballerina version 0.97.1

Answer (score 0):

You cannot retrieve IP address from http request. Ballerina has Remote host/port in endpoint to construct the address. Please check following code snippet.

```
@http:ResourceConfig {
    path:"/local",
    methods:["GET"]
}
sample (endpoint caller, http:Request req) {
    string remoteHost = caller.remote.host;
    int remotePort = caller.remote.port;

}
```

Comment: Thanks, Chamil. This is the correct answer for the question I have raised. So I will keep the question as it is so others can refer. But my actual requirement is to get the remote address at the ballerina filter level, in which I don't have the endpoint data. I have only filter context and http request only. Can we get it at the filter level as well?

Comment: What do you mean by Ballerina filter level?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible in the absence of an endpoint. However a discussion is going on related to this and and some other requirements.